# How to select a certain element from a list that matches a delegate c#

Tags: c#

I have a method that takes a delegate as parameter (lets say action) which is set to null. When I call that method with a parameter I need to select from a list an element that matches that delegate by invoking that delegate. When I don`t pass a delegate as parameter it needs to take in consideration all the elements of that list.

```
public List<Reducere> Reduceri { get; set; }

public void AplicaReduceri(Func<Reducere, string> selector = null)
{
    if (selector != null)
    {
         //here I need to select a Reducere from the list 
         //that matches that delegate by invoking the delegate
    }
    else
    {
         //here I need to take in consideration all the elements of that list
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Besides - didn't you just describe `Where()`  ?

Comment: What do you mean `matches that delegate`? The function returns `string`, not `bool` so you have to perform some additional logic to decide that an item matches or not. Assuming this is performed by a `Func<Reducere,bool>` function called `filter`, you can just write `var result=(filter!=null):Reduceri.Where(filter):Reduceri;`

Comment: I am not sure if it needs to be func or action, so what i am asking is for some suggestions of how should i implement that code.

Comment: This is what i need to do:

Comment: In class Catalog write a method which takes optionally a generic delegate which can allow to select a discount from a list of discounts in class Catalog:
 ->if the delegate is specified, the methods needs to obtain the discount specified by invoking the delegate, otherwise it needs to take in consideration all the discounts from the list

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. **ALL** the elements of `List<Reducere>` can be used with the delegate `Func<Reducere, string>`

Comment: I think it would help us understand your problem if you could submit an example of an **selector** function. And, what are you planning to do with the string return value from selector ?